# Nest could not find GraphQLModule element

Tags: graphql, nest, nestjs, e2e-testing

I'm trying to write the e2e test for my backend app (nestjs, grpahql, mongodb).
This is my test:

```js
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import {
    ApolloServerTestClient,
    createTestClient,
} from 'apollo-server-testing';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { UserModule } from '../src/user/user.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import config from '../src/environments/environment';

describe('User', () => {
    let app: INestApplication;
    let apolloClient: ApolloServerTestClient;

    beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [UserModule, MongooseModule.forRoot(config.mongoURI)],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();

    const module: GraphQLModule = moduleFixture.get<GraphQLModule>(
        GraphQLModule,
    );
    apolloClient = createTestClient((module as any).apolloServer);
    });

    it('should get users', async () => {
    const { query } = apolloClient;
    const result: any = await query({
        query: gql`
        query {
            getUsers {
            _id
            name
            }
        }
        `,
        variables: {},
    });
    console.log(result);
    });
});
```

I face this error:

> Nest could not find GraphQLModule element (this provider does not exist in the current context)

Could someone share a working example or point me what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like GraphQLModule is not imported in the scope of your TestModule. If so, the context will never be able to provide it using `get()`.

Also, this might not help you but this is what we do in our projects:

```js
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const TCP_PORT = 4242;
    const testingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    gqlClient = new ApolloClient({
      uri: `http://localhost:${TCP_PORT}/graphql`,
      fetch: fetch as any,
      cache: new InMemoryCache({
        addTypename: false,
      }),
    });

    app = testingModule.createNestApplication();
    await app.listen(TCP_PORT);
  });
```

I did not add all the imports but here are the most relevant:

```js
import ApolloClient, { gql, InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-boost';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

*I assume you know the other ones and/or don't need them*